Why is OpenCV's matrix addition function not clipping when I add a uint8 variable with a value of 200 to a uint8 variable with a value of 100?
I am working my way through PyImageUniversity and am familiarizing myself with matrix addition and subtraction in Python using NumPy and the OpenCV library.
I have Python 3.11.4, OpenCV 4.10.0-dev, and NumPy 1.25.2.
I'm running the following command:
 20 added = cv2.add(np.uint8([200]), np.uint8([100]))
 21 subtracted = cv2.subtract(np.uint8([50]), np.uint8([100]))
 22 print("max of 255: {}".format(added))
 23 print("min of 0: {}".format(subtracted))

and I receive the following outputs:
max of 255: [[300.]
 [  0.]
 [  0.]
 [  0.]]
min of 0: [[-50.]
 [  0.]
 [  0.]
 [  0.]]

The expected output is
max of 255: [[255]]
min of 0: [[0]]


general advice: don't use version-specific tags ("python-3.11"). those limit your reach. rarely is such a tag appropriate (e.g. when the issue requires that specific version and any other doesn't show the issue)
